# What does it mean when the console displays ->?

Tags: mysql

Rookie question.

I was performing some mysql processes, and then the console displays an indented -> as in the image below, instead of the normal console prompt:

[image]

What does that mean? I can't do anything with it there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means that the sentence is not completed.

To end a sentence inside a mysql session, you have to type `;`<kbd>⏎</kbd>.

By the way, you couldn't do a `cat` inside a mysql session.